# Horse race program, function call ignored

Tags: c++

When printing out the code, it runs, but does not seem to run the `coinflip()` function. Currently only trying to print out the first horse string, randomly moving forward.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

string h0 = "0................";
string h1 = "1................";
string h2 = "2................";
string h3 = "3................";
string h4 = "4................";
int position0 = 0;
string coinflip0(string h0);

int main(){

   cout << "Press Enter to begin! " <<endl;
   cin.ignore();
   std::cout << h0 << endl; //print string
   cout << h1 << endl;
   cout << h2 << endl;
   cout << h3 << endl;
   cout << h4 << endl;

//      srand(time(NULL));//time goes back to zero for each loop

   while(h0.at(16) != 0) {
        cout << "\n Press Enter to continue " << endl;
        cin.ignore();

        string coinflip0(h0); // call function
        cout << h0 << endl; //print new string
   } //end while
} // end main

string coinflip0(string h0) {

   // find random number(0 or 1)
   int num = rand() % 2;
        cout << num << endl;
   position0 = position0 + num;

   if(num==1){
        std::swap(h0[position0], h0[position0+1]);
   } // end if

   return h0;
}//end coin flip
```

Output:

```
Press Enter to begin!

0................
1................
2................
3................
4................

 Press Enter to continue

0................

 Press Enter to continue

0................

 Press Enter to continue

0................

 Press Enter to continue
```

Comment: Not knowing how to call a function should fall within "simple typographic error", or we need another flag category for it. Among the other perplexing details in your code is why you're doing `while(h0.at(16) != 0)` and what you think that will do?

Comment: I was trying to check if the last character in the string was a zero, and if it was, the loop would stop. That's the way that I found to do it, though there might be a much easier way that I did not find.

Comment: `0` is not the same thing as `'0'`, so I don't see why that would ever work, i.e. why your loop wouldn't continue forever. You're checking for the character with the integer value `0` a.k.a. `'\0'` a.k.a. `NUL`, not the ASCII digit `'0'` (which has the integer value `48`). And doing that doesn't make sense, and isn't useful in any real-world situation I can think up (since `'\0'` is typically only used as the string-ending character).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string coinflip0(h0); // call function
```

This isn't actually a function call. It's a variable declaration, similar to:

```
string coinflip0 = h0;
```

To call the function leave out `string`. A simple `coinflip0(h0)` will do the trick. And I take it you want to assign the result back to `h0`, so do that, too:

```
h0 = coinflip0(h0);
```